# ASP.NET MVC get list of database entries with a certain property

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I am trying to get a list of all entries in my database that a certain one of their bool properties is false. I used a foreach loop to get the list but I was hoping to find a more optimized way to do this.
this is the controller code I used:

```
 private DataBaseEntities db = new DataBaseEntities();

public ActionResult ApproveUsersList()
        {                        
             List<ApproveUserViewModel> unapprovedUsers = new List<ApproveUserViewModel>();
             foreach (User dbUser in db.Users)
             {
                 if (!dbUser.Approved)
                 {
                     ApproveUserViewModel model = new ApproveUserViewModel();
                     unapprovedUsers.Add(model);
                 }

             }

             return View(unapprovedUsers.ToList());

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var found = db.Users.Where(w => !w.Approved).Select(s => new ApproveUserViewModel { Approved = s.Approved,... }).ToList();
            unapprovedUsers.AddRange(found);
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not Linq?

```
var _unapprovedUsers= unapprovedUsers.Where(m => !m.Approved).ToList();
```